# Xampp is not running on ubuntu

Tags: apache2, php, nginx, xampp

I have nginx ,Apache2 ,Xampp installed on Ubuntu 12.04

Nginx is running on port 80

First I stopped Apache2 using `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

Now I started Xampp using `/opt/lampp/lampp restart`

I got :

```
root@maye:/opt/lampp/etc# /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a...
XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache is not running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL is not running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is not running.
XAMPP stopped.
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

I know nginx is also running on same port so I changed the port number from

80 to 8008 in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

But still when  I'm trying to run my application on port 8008 it is not working for me. Kindly help me out ?

Comment: have u restarted the nginx after changing the port ???

Answer (score 3):

It pretty much tells you what is wrong:

```
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
```

XAMPP doesn't start apache because another webserver is  running. Seems it doesn't like nignx even though you changed the port. XAMPP also doesn't start its own MySQL server because you are running another one.